# TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property 'quantity' of object '#<Object>'

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, redux-toolkit

I'm trying to modify the field quantity of obj meal in the array orderedList.
This is the error:

---

TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property 'quantity' of object '#'

---

How I can change this state.

---

Please help.Please help.Please help.Please help.Please help.Please help.Please help.
Please help.Please help.Please help.Please help.Please help.Please help.Please help.

---

```
import {createSlice} from "@reduxjs/toolkit";

const menuList = [
    {
        id: 'm1',
        name: 'Sushi',
        description: 'Finest fish and veggies',
        price: 22.99,
        quantity: 0
    },
    {
        id: 'm2',
        name: 'Schnitzel',
        description: 'A german specialty!',
        price: 16.5,
        quantity: 0
    },
    {
        id: 'm3',
        name: 'Barbecue Burger',
        description: 'American, raw, meaty',
        price: 12.99,
        quantity: 0
    },
    {
        id: 'm4',
        name: 'Green Bowl',
        description: 'Healthy...and green...',
        price: 18.99,
        quantity: 0
    },
];

const initialStateMeals = {
    menuList,
    orderedList: [],
    numberOfOrderedMeals: 0,
    showCart: false,
    totalAmount: 0
}

const counterSlice = createSlice({
    name: 'meals',
    initialState: initialStateMeals,
    reducers: {
        add(state, action) {
            state.numberOfOrderedMeals += +action.payload.input;
            let totalAmountTemp = state.totalAmount + action.payload.meal.price * action.payload.input;
            state.totalAmount = +totalAmountTemp.toFixed(2);

            let mealIsInList = state.orderedList.filter(meal => meal.id === action.payload.meal.id).length > 0;

            if (!mealIsInList) {
                state.orderedList.push(action.payload.meal);
                state.orderedList.filter(meal => meal.id === action.payload.meal.id)[0].quantity = 1;
                //on this line I have this error
                //TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property 'quantity' of object '#<Object>'
            } else {
            }
        },
        remove(state, action) {
            state.numberOfOrderedMeals -= +action.payload.input;
        }
        ,
        closeCart(state) {
            state.showCart = false;
        }
        ,
        showCart(state) {
            state.showCart = true;
        }
    }
});

export default counterSlice.reducer;
export const mealsAction = counterSlice.actions;
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

My guess here is that redux-toolkit is protecting you from mutating the action's `payload` object as this mutation could leak out into any other reducer listening for the same action.

Instead of pushing into the array, and then iterating it again *just to find the element you pushed*, which will be the last element in the array, BTW, you could just create a new object with the properties you want and push this into the array instead.

```
if (!mealIsInList) {
  state.orderedList.push({
    ...action.payload.meal,
    quantity: 1,
  });
}
```

Comment: but isn't redux toolkit using immer. we can mutate state

Comment: @AmineDa. Yes, with RTK and it's implementation of ImmerJS under-the-hood you can write mutable reducer functions. This means you can write reducer functions that mutate the ***state***. Mutating/reassigning the action object properties would still be invalid. In OP's original code the last array item is a reference to the action payload and thus not assignable.

Comment: I've encountered a similar problem with RTKQuery's data. It'd be nice if I can get an official documentation stating this.