# Redux TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property 'liked' of object '#<Object>'

Tags: reactjs, redux

I'm new to Redux and trying to modify the liked field of listTreeItem, in an array of objects stored in the Redux store. but I'm getting the following error;

```
Cannot assign to read only property 'liked' of object '#<Object>'
```

I tried cloning the object at setListTreeItems, and some other methods but none of them eliminated the above error.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69095445/typeerror-cannot-assign-to-read-only-property-quantity-of-object-object) is a similar question, but I'm not satisfied with the accepted answer. I believe that there should be some official way to just update a single field of one object in an object array stored in Redux store.

I need to avoid looping through all elements of the array which may chew up the memory and degrade the performance when the list gets larger, even just for a single field change.

Below is my code of the Redux slice;

```
export const sliceListTreeItems  = createSlice({
name:'listTreeItems',
initialState:{listTreeItems:[]},
reducers:{
    setListTreeItems: (state,action)=>
    {
        var clonedItems = action.payload.map((o)=>{ return {...o} });
        state.listTreeItems = clonedItems;
    },prepare(data) {
        return {
            payload: {
            data
            }
        }
    },
    setListTreeItemLiked:(state,action)=>
    {
        var its=current(state).listTreeItems.filter(a=>a.id==action.payload.id);
        if (its.length>0)
        {
            its[0].liked=action.payload.liked;
            
        }
        
      }
   }
});
```

Can anyone please suggest to me the best way to change the 'liked' field without getting a big performance hit? any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Aren't you supposed to return the new state instead of mutating the one given to you? I don't use redux but that was the whole takeaway I got from it - [Rules of Reducers](https://redux.js.org/tutorials/fundamentals/part-3-state-actions-reducers#rules-of-reducers)

Comment: @caTS Yes, I'm ok to return a new state instead of mutating, but I'm not sure whether it will or will not affect the performance when the array gets much bigger. I'm not clear whether Redux stores the whole new state or only the changes by comparing the old and new states. It can happen in hundreds of occurrences, and will it store that number of copies of the whole object array in the memory? what will happen for example, if 5000 elements are modified 200 times? will Redux store 5000x200 elements in state memory?